# Laravel Request Validation, unique_if?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I know that there is already required_if validation of Laravel. Is there any validation that uses unique_if? I will just use this validation, if the action is add, the data should be unique in library_name, while if action is update, it will be disabled

```
private function validateRequest($oRequest)
    {
        $aData = $oRequest->validate([
            'idx'                 => 'required_if:action,==,Update',
            'library_name'        => 'unique:tbl_library,library_name|min:3|max:100|nullable',
            'sub_component_idx'   => 'exists:tbl_sub_component,idx|integer|max:11|required',
            'library_description' => 'min:3|max:1000|nullable',
            'library_psd'         => 'nullable',
            'library_html'        => 'nullable',
            'library_css'         => 'nullable',
            'library_js'          => 'nullable',
            'tags'                => 'nullable'
        ]);

        return $aData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use like this.
Here left email is field name. users is table name and email is field name inside table users.

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $this->id,
```

Let me explain if $this->id is present on the request that mean its a update request. then it will check for unique with rest of the data on table users with email field. If we are going to insert new record then unique will check with all data we have.